# how to Send data to a wcf service ChanellFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am trying to send data (I´m a client) from my web application to a wcf service, and I need to do it with a Channelfactory; From the SoapUI I got the following information:
[image: SoapUI]

And object explorer is VS2015 I got this:
[image: objectExplorer]

I've made a Console Application to test the connection like this:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://10.10.1xxxxxxxxxx4");
        ChannelFactory<SI_Certificados_OutMsg> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<SI_Certificados_OutMsg>(myBinding, myEndpoint);
        var defaultCredentials = myChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find<ClientCredentials>();
        myChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "user";
        myChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "123132";

        SI_Certificados_OutMsg serv = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
        DT_Certificados_DTO cert = new DT_Certificados_DTO();
        // HERE SUPPOSED TO SEND THE DATA TO BE CONSUMED

        myChannelFactory.Close();
        Console.Read();

    }
```

I am a little confused in what I need to do to send data to Nit_proveedor, ciudad etc... as showed in the SoapUI image.

Knowing that the DT_Certificados_DTO is a partial class that is shown in the reference.cs, and Interface SI_Certificados_OutMsg that not have the option of send the serv.Tipo_Impuesto, serv.NIT_Proveedor etc...

Comment: for this I need to do it with the Chanelfactory --- why? why not use proxy? and why WCF, not webapi, etc?

Comment: becasuse this https://www.codeproject.com/tips/558163/difference-between-proxy-and-channel-factory-in-wc

Comment: That is not requirement from a user's perspective.

Comment: hi lei-yang the ChannelFactory class to construct a channel between the client and the service without the need of a proxy. But if you have an idea to solve via proxy or channel? Welcome to your suggestion

Comment: in my first comment i mentioned **webapi**, which might be more recommended.